# SQL Server changing data type from decimal(18,7) to decimal(23,15)

Tags: sql-server, decimal

One of my fields has datatype decimal(18,7). I would like to change it to decimal(23,15). When I attempt it, get error message about "Saving changes not permitted.... require the following tables to be dropped and re-created.... can't be re-created or enable the option Preventing saving changes that rquire that table to be re-create"

Where do I change options to allow table to be dropped and re-created? I have nothing valuable in this table, I can easily drop the table manually and re-create it manually, but would rather have SQL Server do it for me.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as it says, it is in the options. Which are in the menu.

And in the documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895146.aspx

> To change this option, on the Tools menu, click Options, expand
>   Designers, and then click Table and Database Designers. Select or
>   clear the Prevent saving changes that require the table to be
>   re-created check box.